# How to get command output in the powershell script?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I want to wrote a little script that show me all teams in microsoft teams software.

```
Write-host "XXX"
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Connect-MicrosoftTeams;
Write-host "XXX"
Get-Team
```

But after the script runs "get-team" command, it show no result for that command.
What am I doing wrong? What should I do, to get the output of "Get-Team" command showing in powershell window?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Get-Team cmdlet supports retrieving teams with particular properties/information, including all teams that a specific user belongs to, all teams that have been archived, all teams with a specific display name, or all teams in the organization.

```
Get-Team
   [-User <String>]
   [-Archived <Boolean>]
   [-Visibility <String>]
   [-DisplayName <String>]
   [-MailNickName <String>]
   [-NumberOfThreads <Int32>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/get-team?view=teams-ps#examples